# Error with linking scene builder wtih my java code

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have tried to link my fxml code generated in my scene builder but I am not shure what I am doing wrong I constantly get these error messages so this is code of my main class

```
public class Main extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage s) throws Exception {
    
    
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Main.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    s.setScene(scene);
    s.setTitle("JavaFX");
    s.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
 }
}
```

And this is my fxml code:

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

  <AnchorPane prefHeight="389.0" prefWidth="576.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1">
    <children>
    <Button layoutX="257.0" layoutY="182.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
    </children>
  </AnchorPane>
```

Here is the module code:

```
module HelloFX {

requires javafx.graphics;
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires java.desktop;
requires javafx.base;   
}
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
   at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class hellofx.Main
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:890)
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics) cannot access class hellofx.Main (in module HelloFX) because module HelloFX does not export hellofx to module javafx.graphics
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:802)
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
   at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
   at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
```

Comment: Please post your module-info.java file. You need to add `exports hellofx` if that is your module.

Comment: @DustinR I have added  `exports hellofx` and now it works thanks a lot :)

Comment: Perfect, glad to hear it!